# Unable to find SignalR trace logs on disk

Tags: signalr

I tried following links to generate server side SignalR trace on my production environment:

1. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#server_text
2. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Tracing-on-the-server-side

But, trace is not getting saved on disk as mentioned in the links(e.g., "default_traces.txt" or "transports.log.txt" respectively).

Please suggest where trace log file get saved?

I also checked following folders mentioned in first tutorial:

```
 C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1

 C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC1
```

But nothing related with SignalR found there. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In my environment (VS2015 + IIS Express) log files are stored in web application folder (folder with web.config).

Be sure that your application pool has write permission on logs folder.

Also check SignalR error on client side. It can direct you to the cause of the problem.
For example, if client receives response 401 (Not authorized) (for example, on `$.connection.hub.start()`) it could mean that authentication middleware can not authenticate the client and responds with 401 without passing the request further through OWIN pipeline to SignalR. In this case SignalR does not emit any logs (it doesn't know about any request).